# Read Android ID by NFC or similar device

Tags: android, unique, nfc

I am looking for a way to somehow scan android device (for example using NFC scanner), and read the unique ID of that android device.

The device ID would then be inserted into web application ran on the PC.

Is there a way to do this somehow?

Thanks

Comment: you will need some app running on that device to get the ID and make it available over NFC, in which case, you can probably just send it to the web application directly without NFC. Also Android ID is deprecated due to privacy reasons. Android 10 and above will not  provide this for regular apps. see [Unique IDs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) Please provide more details and a minimum reproducable code. If you're looking for ideas/approaches, better place for is places like reddit (like r/androiddev)

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique ID related to NFC.

Android provides a random ID number for security reason as at the NFC level, the ID only has to be different from other Tags/Devices that are in range at the same time to prevent card clash, thus a random number provides that.

You can of course create a Host Emulated Tag on an Android Device with HCE service installed on the Device that will return a static and Unique piece of Data that could be used instead.